# How to add image upload functionality in Netlify CMS

Tags: netlify-cms

Hi I'm new to Netlify CMS I just learned about it from a blog

so I have config.yml that creates two input fields in Netlify CMS
[image]
Sample:

```
collections:
  - name: 'team'
    label: 'Team'
    folder: 'src/team'
    create: true
    slug: '{{slug}}'
    fields:
      - { label: 'Team Member', name: 'title', widget: 'string' }
      - { label: 'Bio', name: 'bio', widget: 'markdown' }
```

I'm just wondering how can I add input field for the image

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
{ label: "Image", name: "thumbnail", widget: "image"}
```

into one of your fields

```
collections:
  - name: 'team'
    label: 'Team'
    folder: 'src/team'
    create: true
    slug: '{{slug}}'
    fields:
      - { label: 'Team Member', name: 'title', widget: 'string' }
      - { label: 'Bio', name: 'bio', widget: 'markdown' }
      - { label: "Image", name: "thumbnail", widget: "image"}
```

Source: https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/add-to-your-site/